# How to pass a class to a function in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to pass a class as an argument in Kotlin so that I can reuse a method, how would I convert this Java function to a Kotlin function?

```
 public void goToActivity(Activity activity, Class classs) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, classs);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: This discussion may help you: [Passing java class as parameter](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/passing-java-class-as-parameter/1954/2). Also: If you use an Ide like android studio, you can automatically convert Java to Kotlin

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A class is passed in this format in Kotlin `ClassName::class.java`.

This seems to be the correct way to do it:

```
fun Context.goToActivity(activity: Activity, classs: Class<*>?) {
    val intent = Intent(activity, classs)
    startActivity(intent)
    activity.finish()
}
```

And an example of how the method is called:

```
goToActivity(this, OneMainActivity::class.java)
```